# Remove URLs of old site from Google index permanently

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-index

Lets say I have a site called `oldsite.com`. Then I bought a new domain `newsite.com`. I transferred the content from `oldsite.com` to `newsite.com`. In the process I also updated the URLs of all the posts and pages. I am redirecting `oldsite.com` to `newsite.com`.

How do I permanently remove all the URLs of `oldsite.com` from the Google index? I am doing so because `newsite.com` is quite new and doesn't have great many links pointing to it. Webmaster tool only allows to hide a URL temporarily, I want to permanently hide them.

Comment: Google will automatically remove URLs that redirect as long as the redirects are permanent.  What type of redirects are you using and how long has it been?  It may take Google a few weeks.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have tried this technique, and yes redirects are permanent. Even after 2 months i can still see URLs of old site in Google's index.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Why the urls are still in the google's index ?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is if you have redirects in place.  Can you disclose the actual sites so that we can take a look?

Comment: I can confirm that your redirects are indeed 301 permantent.  If I use a `site:` query on Google for your old site, I see two listing: one is the home page and the other is a wordpress admin link.   Both redirect.  Google has clearly crawled the home page because it cached the home page from the new site.   The second link redirects to 404 not found.    I would expect Google to remove both of those eventually.   I've never seen Google keep them for so long.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller you are seeing only two urls because i have removed them manually today using remove urls tools from webmaster.  Will they re-appear after some time ?

Comment: Have you tried to use the [change of address tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en) in Google Search Console yet?

Comment: Yes i did. It at least 2 months ago. Will urls re-appear after some time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want search engines to stop crawling your old website, just configure a **robots.txt** in your DocumentRoot of oldsite.com to let them know:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

**Additionally**

you can then go to Google Webmaster Tools and delete them temporarily. That should be enough until the crawler visits you again. To permanently delete it from the web...you have to do exactly that --> no DNS-resolving = no requests on oldsite.com

**Just to make sure:**

All Rewrites from oldsite.com to newsite.com should include [R=permanent] as a parameter.

Comment: As i am redirecting `oldsite.com` to `newsite.com`. Does this create any problems for `newsite.com` ? Will search engines still able to index contents of `newsite.com`

Comment: Assuming that your oldsite and newsite don't share the same DocumentRoot, newsite.com would still be crawled. http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html for more details...and for clarification: put one robots.txt in each DocumentRoot (one for oldsite and one for newsite) and set the oldsite-robots.txt to disallow everything, while you allow everything in the other one.

Comment: When a robot looks for the "/robots.txt" file for URL, it strips the path component from the URL (everything from the first single slash), and puts "/robots.txt" in its place.

For example, for "http://www.example.com/shop/index.html, it will remove the "/shop/index.html", and replace it with "/robots.txt", and will end up with "http://www.example.com/robots.txt".

Comment: I'd be delighted if you could mark the answer as 'correct' if it was for you :) Otherwise let me know so I can help...

Answer (score 1):

This looks like migration, so you have to be patient in order for Google to acknowledge all the changes you made. Crawl your current website with tools like Screaming Frog or Website Auditor, to detect possible redirect chains and loops who potentially can confuse search engines. Use fetch and render in your Search Console on your old domain to see if Google is seeing those permanent redirects you previously created.

If you haven't verified your both domains in Search Console, do that and ask for **Change of address** https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en
To be able to do so, you will have to be owner of both domains in Search Console.

**Extra note:**

Also, reach out to all webmasters where you have backlinks to update them with new domain name. After all, give Google some time to get new data (up to one month).